# Guavaで、Lists.transform()とFluentIterable.from().transform().toList()の違いは？

Tags: java, guava

どちらもリストを変換できますが、どう違うのかを共有します。まずは書き方。

## 1. `Lists.transform()`の場合：

```
List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
List<String> newList = Lists.transform(list, new Function<String, String>() {
    public String apply(String input) {
        System.out.println("transform -> " + input);
        return input + "_add";
    }
});
```

## 2. `FluentIterable.from().transform().toList()`の場合：

```
List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
List<String> newList = FluentIterable.from(list).transform(new Function<String, String>() {
    public String apply(String input) {
        System.out.println("transform -> " + input);
        return input + "_add";
    }
}).toList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 確認コード

```
System.out.println(list.toString());
System.out.println(newList.toString());
list.add("ddd");
System.out.println(list.toString());
System.out.println(newList.toString());
```

### 1. `Lists.transform()`の場合：

`Function`で定義された関数は遅延評価され、参照される際に変換関数が呼ばれます。よって、元のリストを変更した場合、その変更が**変換先のリストにも反映されます**。

実行結果：

```
[aaa, bbb, ccc]
    transform -> aaa
    transform -> bbb
    transform -> ccc
[aaa_add, bbb_add, ccc_add]
[aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd]
    transform -> aaa
    transform -> bbb
    transform -> ccc
    transform -> ddd
[aaa_add, bbb_add, ccc_add, ddd_add]
```

### 2. `FluentIterable.from().transform().toList()`の場合：

リストがコピーされるため、元のリストを変更しても、その変更が**変更先のリストに反映されません**。

実行結果：

```
[aaa, bbb, ccc]
    transform -> aaa
    transform -> bbb
    transform -> ccc
[aaa_add, bbb_add, ccc_add]
[aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd]
[aaa_add, bbb_add, ccc_add]
```

## どちらを使うべきか

変更先のリストが変更元のリストと同じ要素で必要な場合は`Lists.transform()`を使用し、変更元のリストと同じである必要がない、一度きりの変換のみでよければ`FluentIterable.from().transform().toList()`を使用するほうが良いでしょう。

上記を理解していれば`Lists.transform()`を必要に応じて使用してよいと思いますが、なんでもかんでも`Lists.transform()`を使用していると、参照の度に変換関数が呼ばれ、その変換処理が重たい場合、思わぬボトルネックとなりますので注意が必要です。
`Guava`をよく知らない技術者がいる場合、混乱の元になりますので明示的に使い分ける方が良いと思います。

なお、`FluentIterable.from().transform()`で`FluentIterable`型のリストを取得した場合、**`Lists.transform()`と同様の振る舞いをします**。リストのコピーにしたければ必ず`toList()`で受け取る必要があります。

参考URL：
[guava - difference between Lists.transform(…, …) and FluentIterable.from(…).transform(…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897767/guava-difference-between-lists-transform-and-fluentiterable-from)
[guavaライブラリのLists.transformを使う際の注意点](http://qiita.com/yuichielectric/items/2f5dff4e1df896c1ae24)